# How to suppress deletion with Hibernate CustomInterceptor

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to use a Hibernate CustomInterceptor to stop entries from getting deleted, but it doesn't seem to work.
Although the onDelete method in the CustomerInterceptor is triggered, the row is still getting deleted. I thought that by not calling "super.onDelete" the deletion would not go ahead?
Is there some way of achieving what I want using CustomInterceptor?

```
@Override
public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    
    if (entity instanceof VulnerableBO) {
        VulnerableBO p = (VulnerableBO)entity;
        log.warn(String.format("WARNING - suppressing deletion of entry from vulnerable ! P Id=%d, N=%s, V=%s", p.getPI(),p.getPN(),p.getPV()));
    } else {
        super.onDelete(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress any operation inside `Interceptor`, you should throw `CallbackException`. Check out the [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#onDelete(java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Serializable,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%5B%5D)).

```java
@Override
public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    if (entity instanceof VulnerableBO) {
        VulnerableBO p = (VulnerableBO)entity;
        throw new CallbackException(String.format("WARNING - suppressing deletion of entry from vulnerable ! P Id=%d, N=%s, V=%s", p.getPI(),p.getPN(),p.getPV()));
    } else {
        super.onDelete(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
    }
}
```